# Can I use the .NET Google GData client in a MonoTouch or MonoDroid app?

Tags: xamarin.ios, gdata-api, gdata, xamarin.android

Is it possible to reference a library such as the Google GData .NET client in a MonoTouch or MonoDroid app?  It would make integration with Google's services much easier.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get that library (or any library, really) to work against MonoTouch or Mono for Android you'd need to compile it against that profile. Out of the box the GData client won't compile against those profiles because it has some dependencies that aren't compatible. There's a [post up here](http://mikebluestein.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/using-monotouch-with-the-net-library-for-the-google-data-api/) by Mike Bluestein that talks about getting it working with MonoTouch. The same approach should also apply to Mono for Android.