# Monodroid google api example

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm new on Monodroid platform, I wonder is there good references/books/examples that integrate Monodroid with Google javascript API (Drive, Calendar, Contact, etc.). What I know is that there Client Library for .NET/C# but I fail integrate it with Monodroid (not understand to use OAuth on Monodroid too). [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398643/can-i-use-the-net-google-gdata-client-in-a-monotouch-or-monodroid-app) but it's a bit old.